# Сравнение значений элементов внутри многомерного массива и вывод преобладающего

Tags: php, массивы, сравнение

Доброго времени суток!
Помогите решить задачку, из AD получаю многомерный массив с юзерами:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [login] => Balashov_D
        [boss] => Козловский Валерий 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [login] => Bezmagarychnyy_E
        [boss] => Козловский Валерий
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [login] => Golovachev_A
        [boss] => Козловский Валерий
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [login] => Kozlovskiy_V
        [boss] => Семутенко Виталий Александрович
```

Надо сравнить боссов у пользователей и вывести того кто преобладает, т.е. в данном случае Козловский В. По логике думаю разбить по боссам на разные массивы и сравнить кол-во, но как это сделать не знаю, подскажите пожалуйста.
З.Ы. запрос выводит разных пользователей с разных OU и соотвественно с разными боссами, поэтому никаких значений я заранее не знаю.

Comment: вам нужно использовать http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php

Comment: Вы пишете `Надо сравнить боссов у пользователей и вывести того кто преобладает, т.е. в данном случае Козловский В.` как Вы определили, что Козловский самый важный/сильный/влиятельный...?

Comment: Неправильно выразился, нужен тот который прописан у большинства юзеров в массиве

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код не претендует на оптимальное решение и на грамотное оформление, просто возможно будет полезен:

```
    $stack = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        if (!isset($stack[$value['boss']])) {
            $stack[$value['boss']] = 1;
        } else {
            $stack[$value['boss']] ++;
        }
    }
    var_dump(array_search(max($stack), $stack));
```

, где `$array` - ваш массив.

Comment: только `!isset`

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает

Answer (score 1):

Ну или так. Ваш массив:

```
$arr = [
     ['login' => 'Balashov_D', 'boss' => 'Козловский Валерий' ],
     ['login' => 'Bezmagarychnyy_E', 'boss' => 'Козловский Валерий' ],
     ['login' => 'Kozlovskiy_V', 'boss' => 'Семутенко Виталий Александрович' ],
     ['login' => 'Golovachev_A', 'boss' => 'Козловский Валерий' ],
     ['login' => 'Kozlovskiy_V', 'boss' => 'Семутенко Виталий Александрович' ],
     ['login' => 'Kozlovskiy_V', 'boss' => 'Семутенко Виталий Александрович' ],
     ['login' => 'Kozlovskiy_V', 'boss' => 'Семутенко Виталий Александрович' ],
     ['login' => 'Kozlovskiy_V', 'boss' => 'Семутенко Виталий Александрович' ],
];
```

Получаем босса:

```
$mainBosses = array_count_values(array_column($arr, 'boss'));
asort($mainBosses);
end($mainBosses); 
echo(key($mainBosses));
```